# iOS swift 3 - custom table cell, but no data is showing on the tableview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift3

I have a custom table cell as follows. I am trying to display an image(left), label(middle), another image(right). I created xib and associated the xib with this custom table cell class and I am using "sensorStatusTableViewCell" as an identifier. I added SensorStatusTableViewCell to the Custom Class as well.

```
class SensorStatusTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var sensorImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var sensorNameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var sensorOnOffStatusLabel: UIImageView!
}


class ViewController: SuperViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var sensors: [String] = ["Door Sensor"]
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var sensorTableView: UITableView = UITableView()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    sensors = ["Door Sensor"]
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = CGFloat(200)
    sensorTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight);
    sensorTableView.dataSource = self
    sensorTableView.delegate = self

    sensorTableView.register(SensorStatusTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "sensorStatusTableViewCell")
    self.scrollView.addSubview(sensorTableView)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell:SensorStatusTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sensorStatusTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SensorStatusTableViewCell

    let sensorImageName = "sensor_door.png"
    let sensorImage = UIImage(named: sensorImageName)
    let sensorImageView = UIImageView(image: sensorImage!)
    cell.sensorImage = sensorImageView

    let sensorLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
    sensorLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
    sensorLabel.text = sensors[0]
    cell.sensorNameLabel = sensorLabel

    let sensorStatusName = "icon_sensor_on.png"
    let sensorStatusImage = UIImage(named: sensorStatusName)
    let sensorStatusImageView = UIImageView(image: sensorStatusImage!)
    cell.sensorOnOffStatusLabel = sensorStatusImageView

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    print("User selected table row \(indexPath.row) and item \(sensors[indexPath.row])")
}
}
```

When I run this, I see a table view, but i don't see a custom table cell. I see only empty table rows.   Is there anything else that I need to do?

Here is my screenshot.

[image]

Comment: That's an odd way of creating a uitableview and cells. Your use of @IBOutlet seems to indicate you have a xib file or storyboard that lays out the scrollView and the tableview cell but then in the cellForRowat() function you're overwriting the cell members.

Comment: It seems you are not providing height for the table view cell. 

You need to implement table view's delegate method -  
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`

Comment: I am following this example. https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/

In this example, there is no height in the code.

Answer (score 0):

TableViewCell's identifier is "sensorStatusTableViewCell". Check Your StoryBoard -> SensorStatusTableViewCell. It's identifier have to be "sensorStatusTableViewCell".